# How to find the different keys for UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I'm using this great code from the [New Font Features at WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-804/):

```
import UIKit

let pointSize : CGFloat = 60.0
let systemFontDesc = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize,
                                             weight: UIFontWeightLight).fontDescriptor
let fractionFontDesc = systemFontDesc.addingAttributes(
    [
        UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [
            [
                UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kFractionsType,
                UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kDiagonalFractionsSelector,
                ],
        ]
    ] )

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))

label.font = UIFont(descriptor: fractionFontDesc, size:pointSize)
label.text = "12/48"
```

The WWDC video shows other uses for UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute such as superiors (e = mc²)

But what are the keys to unlock the other attributes?

The documentation page for [UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifontdescriptorfeaturesettingsattribute) just says that it's an array of dictionaries containing UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey and UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey.

The documentation for those two keys ([type](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifontfeaturetypeidentifierkey) and [selector](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifontfeatureselectoridentifierkey)) just says they are NSNumbers.

For fractions, type is kFractionsType and selector is kDiagonalFractionsSelector

How can I find the keys for other available features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Text will list the hidden features of a font for you:

```
let desc = UIFontDescriptor(name: "Didot", size: 20) as CTFontDescriptor
let f = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(desc,0,nil)
let arr = CTFontCopyFeatures(f)
print(arr as Any)
```

For features that have magic names, you'll have to look in the *SFNTLayoutTypes.h* header.

Comment: Thanks - this works and prints out all the different key options, although it gives only the Int values to be used and not the more descriptive variables for these Ints such as kFractionsType and kDiagonalFractionsSelector

Comment: Correct, but as I said in my answer, the corresponding names are in the header.

Comment: Where/how do you look in the header? I finally found all the different "magic names" here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM09/AppendixF.html

Comment: Really, you don't know how to look in a header??!? Well, simplest is Shift-Command-O S-F-N-T-L Return.